# recycler view automatically scroll up when new items is added

Tags: android-layout

I have working with chat application ..when i have inserted items recycler view get scroll up automatically ..it produces some annoying transition in the view ..how to stop this..

i have use this piece of code.I think this will be cause not sure about that

```
 mChatMessagesRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mChatMessagesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: Remove this line : mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

Comment: i have require this ...i have to load message from bottom to top..this line help to acheive this...any other way to resolve this???